# Timeout doesn't work for F# Async.RunSynchronously when executing an external process

Tags: .net, f#

Starting a potentially slow or hanging process with the code below, will not result in a timeout:

```
open System.Diagnostics

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Async.RunSynchronously(
        async {
            use proc = Process.Start(@"SlowProcess.exe")
            proc.WaitForExit()
        }, timeout = 2000)
    0
```

The workaround is of course to use a timeout in the call to `WaitForExit`, but I'm curious about why the `Async.RunSynchronously` timeout doesn't work in this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way cancellation in F# asynchronous workflows works is that it is collaborative - it will never forcefully kill the thread. It propagates the cancellation token automatically, passes it to operations that support that and checks for cancellation every time the F# async workflow infrastructure gets a chance (typically before running code using `let!` and after it completes). This means that blocking code is not cancelled. A smaller example that illustrates this would be:

```
let work = async {
    try
      printfn "Going to sleep"
      Thread.Sleep(10000)
      printfn "Waking up"  
    finally
      printfn "All completed"
  }
```

If you run this and cancel it immediately, it will print "Going to sleep" and then you'll only get "All completed" after 10 seconds - because the `Thread.Sleep` call is synchronous.

If you want to kill the process when the workflow is cancelled, you should be able to explicitly register a cancellation handler and use the `Kill` method to stop the process - I have not tested this (I don't have a suitable slow process around!), but something like this should do the trick:

```
let work = async {
    let! tok = Async.CancellationToken
    use proc = Process.Start(@"SlowProcess.exe")
    tok.Register(fun () -> proc.Kill()) |> ignore
    proc.WaitForExit()
  }
```

Comment: I just tried the cancellation handler snippet, and it works.